# How to get a part of url between 4th and 5th slashes?

Tags: php, regex

Please help!

I'm on PHP. I have an url: 'http://example.com/articles/123a/view', how do I get '123a' only from this string with regular expression (preg_replace, probably). Can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
^(?:[^/]*/){4}([^/]+)

preg_match('/^(?:[^\\/]*\\/){4}([^\\/]+)/', $str, $match)
```

`$match[1]` will then hold your `123a`.

Comment: I typed this: preg_replace('^(?:[^/]*/){4}([^/]+)', '', http://example.com/articles/123a/view)

Comment: @Andersson83: You forgot the delimiters.

Answer (score 10):

Why Regex?

```
$parts = explode('/', 'http://example.com/articles/123a/view');
echo $parts[4];
```

Comment: The third parameter of `explode` allows you to set a limit. You could set it to `6` to prevent some possible superfluous exploding.